# Fancyhead for unnumbered appendix in R Markdown knit to pdf

Tags: latex, r-markdown

A question about fancyhdr in  R Markdown knitting to pdf.
Can anyone help me to fix the header for the appendix? I have numbered sections in the document, and the fancyhead for pages with the numbered sections is oke. But for the unnumbered appendix, it keeps showing the last numbered section, where I just want the title of the current unnumbered appendix to be shown. Code example below. Thanks!

```
---
title: "Example"
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   - \pagestyle{fancy}
---
\newpage
# Chapter
\newpage
# Appendix {-}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the header like this:

```
---
title: "Example"
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   - \pagestyle{fancy}
---
\newpage
# Chapter
\newpage
# Appendix {-}
\markboth{something here}{something there}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, this works. A follow-up question:  Since I have a lot of appendices, how do i get the name of the appendix in the header? if i use \thesection instead of the "something here", I get the number of the last numbered section.