# Render logo.png in header of pdf output shiny - Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, report, pdf-generation

This is a followup or more a simplification of this question [Error: File header.tex not found in resource path in a rmarkdown generated pdf report from a shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71786935/error-file-header-tex-not-found-in-resource-path-in-a-rmarkdown-generated-pdf-r)

With this Rmarkdown code I can achieve what I want:

**logo.png**

[image]

**report.Rmd**

````
---
geometry: margin=20truemm
fontfamily: mathpazo
fontsize: 11pt
documentclass: article
classoption: a4paper
urlcolor: blue
output: 
    pdf_document:
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   - \pagestyle{fancy}
   - \rhead{\includegraphics[width = .05\textwidth]{logo.png}}
params: 
    scores: NA
---
<!-- ```{r, echo=FALSE} -->
<!-- hist(params$scores) -->
<!-- ``` -->

```{r}
hist(runif(100))
```
````

**Getting desired output: The R logo is in the header:**
[image]

### Now I would like to do the same from a shiny app

##### For this I pass the plot as a *parameter* and uncomment the relevant part in the *report.Rmd* file

relevant part in *report.Rmd* file:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
hist(params$scores)
```
````

**app.R**

```
# Global variables can go here
n <- 200


# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  plotOutput('plot'),
  downloadButton('report', 'Generate Report')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
  
  # create markdown report  ----------------------------------
  
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      params <- list(scores = input$n)
      
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
  
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Error:**

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `logo.png' not found: using draft setting.
```

### I suspect because it works locally logo.png is not found in the temporary file where shiny saves tempReport

But I don't know why this works when knitting from markdown and not when calling it from the shiny app.
I think I have been through of the relevant sites on the internet!
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you already figured out what's the issue. Hence one approach to fix your issue would be to do copy both the report template and the logo to the same temporary directory.

```
# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
  # create markdown report  ----------------------------------
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      td <- tempdir()
      tempReport <- file.path(td, "report.Rmd")
      tempLogo <- file.path(td, "logo.png")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      file.copy("logo.png", tempLogo, overwrite = TRUE)

      params <- list(scores = input$n)

      rmarkdown::render(tempReport,
        output_file = file,
        params = params,
        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
}
```